# Determine if WebBrowser uses plugin to show file instead of download

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Some files can be seen inside WebBrowser (pdf, kml etc). On some browsers there is an activeX plugin to handle those files, while on others the file is being downloaded.

Is there a way to force download the file?

I'm using the classic WebBrowser control and Watin.